# How to match a specific pattern in a longer string in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a few files:

```
java-opentimelineio-0.14.0-beta-1-sources.jar
java-opentimelineio-0.14.0-beta-1.jar
java-opentimelineio-0.14.0.jar
```

I'm trying to use regex to match the file names like this:

```
find . -type f -name "[[:alnum:]]*[.][0-9]*(-beta-)?[0-9]*.jar"
```

I want the regex to match only these:

```
java-opentimelineio-0.14.0-beta-1.jar
java-opentimelineio-0.14.0.jar
```

But I'm getting no matches. From what I understand, a `*` after any character will match zero or more occurrences of that character and a `?` will match zero or one occurrence of that character. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Instead of `-name` you should be using `-regex`

Comment: It is not just about how `find` works, the regex also needs fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
> find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[^/]+-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-beta-[0-9]+)?\.jar'
./java-opentimelineio-0.14.0-beta-1.jar
./java-opentimelineio-0.14.0.jar
```

Keep in mind that the regex can be used with `-regex` option and it must match the whole path.

The `-regextype posix-egrep` option allows using a "simpler" (meaning less escaping is involved) POSIX ERE engine .

*Regex details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` - "version"-like pattern: one or more digits, `.`,  one or more digits, `.`,  one or more digits
- `(-beta-[0-9]+)?` - an optional `-beta-` string and then one or more digits
- `\.jar` - a `.jar` string.